# Wrong sort output due to tabulation separator

Tags: bash, sorting

I have to sort this lines using `sort`:

```
$ echo -e "mariadb-server-10.0\t2\nmariadb-server\t2\nmariadb-server-core-10.0\t2" | sort
mariadb-server-10.0 2
mariadb-server  2
mariadb-server-core-10.0    2
```

but I don't understand why it doesn't work while sorting:

```
$ echo -e "mariadb-server-10.0\nmariadb-server\nmariadb-server-core-10.0" | sort
mariadb-server
mariadb-server-10.0
mariadb-server-core-10.0
```

works perfectly:

Since field are separated by tabs, I've tried `sort -t$'\t' -k1` but it doesn't change anything. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion, yes:

```
LC_ALL=C  sort -d <<EOF
mariadb-server-10.0 2017-04-11 19:09:26.934255687 +0200
mariadb-server  2017-04-11 19:09:46.814225367 +0200
mariadb-server-core-10.0    2017-04-11 19:08:43.304322172 +0200 
EOF
```

gives

```
mariadb-server  2017-04-11 19:09:46.814225367 +0200
mariadb-server-10.0 2017-04-11 19:09:26.934255687 +0200
mariadb-server-core-10.0    2017-04-11 19:08:43.304322172 +0200
```

(which is the expected result).
But, I'm sorry, no explanation. Locales have, for me, always been leading to inexplicable behaviour.